# Transform CSS into SCSS (using BEM)

Tags: html, css, sass

Please help with the code below. How can I create a SCSS one like code in comment.

```
.carousel-button {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-brand-dark);
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;

  &:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-brand-light);
    border: 1px solid white;

    &arrow {
      fill: white;
    }
  }

  &__arrow {
    fill: var(--color-brand-dark);
    transition: fill 0.2s;
  }
}

//THIS VARIANT IS WORKING. I need to convert it in SCSS
**// .carousel-button:hover .arrow {
//   fill: white;
// }**
```

I have done my try with &arrow inside .carousel-button:hover, but it doesn`t work.

Comment: .carousel-button:hover    
.carousel-button__arrow 
{
  fill: white;
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To get `.carousel-button:hover .arrow`, write `.arrow` instead of `&arrow`. The latter becomes `.carousel-button:hoverarrow`, which has no matches.

```scss
.carousel-button {
  /* styles... */

  &:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-brand-light);
    border: 1px solid white;

    /* changed */
    .arrow {
      fill: white;
    }
  }
}
```